# Getting image URL from bucket Amazon Web Service iOS after uploading

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an image that I'm uploading to my bucket in AWS this way:

```
BFTask *task = [BFTask taskWithResult:nil];

        [[task continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {

            self.URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test"]];

            NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
            //NSMutableString *dataString = [NSMutableString new];
            [data writeToURL:self.URL atomically:YES];
            return nil;

        }]continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {

            self.uploadRequest1 = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
            self.uploadRequest1.bucket = S3BucketName;
            self.uploadRequest1.key = S3KeyUploadName1;


            self.uploadRequest1.body = self.URL;
            return nil;
        }];

            AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];

            [[transferManager upload:self.uploadRequest1] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
                if (task.error != nil) {
                    if( task.error.code != AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled
                       &&
                       task.error.code != AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused
                       )
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Upload Failed!");
                    }
                } else {
                    self.uploadRequest1 = nil;
                    NSLog(@"Uploaded!");
                                        }
                return nil;
            }];
```

The code for uploading the image works just fine. When I open my bucket I see the image there.

Now what I want to do is to get the URL of that image, is there a way to get the URL without getting the image again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't get it, you create it like:

**https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKET_NAME/FILE_NAME.jpg**

Answer (score 4):

```
AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];

uploadRequest.body = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
uploadRequest.key = fileName;
uploadReuest.bucket = S3BucketName;
```

> [uploadRequest setACL:AWSS3ObjectCannedACLPublicRead];

Above Answer is right but you must have to set "ACL" to uploadRequest.

In your Question,you are forget to set "ACL".

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the path from Amazon S3 -> Bucket -> Folder -> Image file -> Properties and on right side, you will see something like this..

[image: Get image accessible path from here]

Comment: How to get that link path from iOS objective -C?